# Assign a function to a single letter within jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to make the letter "x" clickable and ad a function that removes the text that this line below creates.

```
$("#user").prepend("<li>Hello! <span id='clickable'>x</span></li>");
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#hello").click(function() {
  $("#user").prepend("<li>Hello! <span id='clickable'>x</span></li>");
  $("#webpage").prepend("<li>Why hello there!!</li>");
  $("#user").children("li").first().click(function(){
   $(this).remove();
  });
  $("#webpage").children("li").first().click(function(){
   $(this).remove();
  });
 });
 $("#goodbye").click(function() {
  $("#user").prepend("<li>Goodbye!</li>");
  $("#webpage").prepend("<li>Goodbye, dear user!</li>");
  $("#user").children("li").first().click(function(){
   $(this).remove();
  });
  $("#webpage").children("li").first().click(function(){
   $(this).remove();
  });

 });
 $("#stop").click(function() {
  $("#user").prepend("<li>Stop copying me!</li>");
  $("#webpage").prepend("<li>Sorry, i meant no offense.</li>");
  $("#user").children("li").first().click(function(){
   $(this).remove();
  });
  $("#webpage").children("li").first().click(function(){
   $(this).remove();
  });
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="CSS/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="CSS/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="jQuery/jQuery.js"></script>
    <script src="talk.js"></script>
    <title>Talk to the web page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Talk to the web page</h1>
      <p>Click a button to say something to the web page. See what it says back!</p>

      <button class="btn btn-primary" id="hello">Say "hello"</button>
      <button class="btn btn-inverse" id="goodbye">Say "goodbye"</button>
      <button class="btn btn-danger" id="stop">Say "stop copying me!"</button>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <h2>You said:</h2>
          <ul class="unstyled" id="user">

          </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
          <h2>The web page said back:</h2>
          <ul class="unstyled" id="webpage">

          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

a clickable letter that removes the text this line above creates.

Comment: What do you want to accomplish? Its confusing. Your span with id `clickable` does not have anything attached to it. Just make sure that after using prepend, you reapply `$("#clickable").off("click").on("click", function(event){})`

Comment: It looks like you already have that..? When I click the `x` item is being deleted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create one click event that uses `.on` (since dynamic content and what not) and remove the parent `li` element:

```
$("#user").on("click", "span.clickable", function() {
    $(this).parent("li").remove();
});
```

Also use the class `clickable` and not the ID (I assume you have more than 1);